# Inequation with indicator functions

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Consider a random variable Z and $x,r > 0$

Now it should hold: $$e^{rZ} =  e^{rZ}  I_{\{Z > u\}} +  e^{rZ}  I_{\{Z \leq u\}}  \geq  e^{rZ}  I_{\{Z > u\}} \overset{!}{>} e^{ru}  I_{\{Z>u\}
}$$

Can this be right?

Comment: If $Z>u$ the LHS is $e^{rZ}$ as is the middle and as is the RHS. But $x>x$ is false for any real $x$.

Comment: Ok you are  right. But I can say something like that: $e^{rZ} > e^{ru} I_{\{Z>u  \}} $

Comment: But I am not sure how I can proof that?

Comment: sure. For if $Z>u$ then since $r>0$, taking exponentials we get $e^{rZ}>e^{ru}$. When $Z\leq u$ the new RHS is zero and the LHS is still positive. So in any case $e^{rZ}>e^{ru} \mathbb{1}_{Z>u}$, as desired—if I am not mistaken.

Comment: Thank you. I got it finally :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the second last part, let say $Z$ is smaller than $u$, it is evaluated to $0$ but $e^{ru}>0$, hence the last part is not correct.

Edit:

It is possible for both sides to be $0$ isn't it? you might want to avoid strict inequality.

Comment: Sorry I forget the indicator function at the end. Will it work now?

Comment: you might want to avoid strict inequality since both sides can be $0$.